# Generate a value from a list of number

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, hash

I have a simple problem that I am not able to solve because of my lack of knowledge, and I couldn't find any clue on the web.

I would like to :

- Generate a "value 1" from a list of number (array of int).
- Generate a "value 2" from a random number.
- Then check the presence of the random number in the list of number by comparing the "value 2" with "value 1".

Why do I would like to generate these values instead of simply do an array search of the random number in the list of number ?

Because there is a necessity of hiding the list of number, and being able to do a fast check just by comparing values.

I have thought about the "hash" method, but there is no way to hash an array of int.

I have also thought about the RSA cryptosystem, generate a "private key" from the list of number and then generate "pubic key" from the random number. But I couldn't find a way to implement it.

I would like to know if there is a way to do what I would like to do ?

Thank you for your help.

---

**Example :**

A server in PHP have a list of number. (Ex: [10, 20, 24, 6, 98])

A client in JS send a number to server. (Ex: 8)

Then

```
// [10, 20, 24, 6, 98] to hashed or key
$computedIntArray = HashedOrRsaEncrypted($ServerIntArray);

// 8 to hashed or key
$computedClientNumber = HashedOrRsaEncrypted($ClientNumber);

// return true if the clienthashedvalue is present in the serverIntArray
$trueOrFalse = IsPresentInArray($computedClientNumber, $computedIntArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For generating, for example 10 non repeating random numbers, you could use a hash table.

```js
var hash = {},
    l = 10,
    r;

while (l) {
   r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
   if (!hash[r]) {
       hash[r] = true;
       l--;
   }
}

console.log(Object.keys(hash).map(Number));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6, you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and add the value until the size of the set has the wanted count.

```js
var hash = new Set,
    l = 10;

while (hash.size < l) {
   hash.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}

console.log([...hash]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. It is not about generating random number, it is about generating a hash or a private key or a value from a list of number and  do the same for a random number (5 for exemple). Then being able to compare the hash or the keys (private/public) or value, in order to know if the random number is present in the list of number.

Comment: right, for testing if a number is already in use, you could use either an object as hash table or a set. but where is the problem?

Comment: I have edited my post and added an example. I start to think that maybe the thing i would like to do is not possible. Sorry i can't find another way to express myself, English is not my native language. Thank you for you help.